# How to extract h2 from one div and print with another div result?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to learn coding with `python` and working on a simple web scraping tool.

I want to extract titles of ads and their prices next to them. Both price and description are defined in `<div>` sections of the page.

Currently I have two for loops, one for price and one for description and I cannot figure out a way how to combine them. I also end up exctracting everything under `<div>` and would like to limit exctraction of title to only `<h2>` tag

My current code is as this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://auto.bazos.cz/bmw/?hledat=&hlokalita=15000&humkreis=50&cenaod=30000&cenado=100000&order=1'

result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
#print(doc.prettify())


price = doc.find_all("div", {"class":"inzeratycena"})
title = doc.find_all("div", {"class":"inzeratynadpis"}).


for div in price:
    print(div.text)


for div in title:
    print(div.text)
```

1. I had to use two for loops, therefore the program first returns `list` of prices and then runs second for loop and returns descriptions, how do I combine price + description in a single loop?
2. For title I am currently extracting everything under the `<div>` tag, how do I limit the extraction to only `<h2>` section inside the `<div>`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the parent container with class `inzeraty` and scrape all needed information of its children in one go. Avoid different `lists` and store your results in a more strutured way like `dicts`.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://auto.bazos.cz/bmw/?hledat=&hlokalita=15000&humkreis=50&cenaod=30000&cenado=100000&order=1'

result = requests.get(url)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text)    
data = []

for e in doc.select('.inzeraty'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.h2.text,
        # and everything that is additionally needed
        'desc':e.select_one('.popis').text,
        'price':e.select_one('.inzeratycena').text
    })

data
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'BMW DISKY + ZIMNÍ GUMY',
  'desc': 'Dobrý den, \nnabízím k prodeji originální BMW Mpaket disky se zimními pneumatikami. \nStav: Velmi dobré \nRozměry: \n2x  245 / 45 / R19\n2x  275 / 40 / R19',
  'price': '  30 000 Kč'},
 {'title': 'alu kola BOLA R18 5x120',
  'desc': 'prodam kola i s pneu (1 sezónu jeté) \nnějaký menší oderky se najdou jinak nakopáná nejsou \njsou to odlehčené disky (1 disk 8-9kg)\nklidně vyměním za nějaký r19 5x120 v černé barvě \nvíce info mail',
  'price': '  30 000 Kč'},...]
```